# While Creating SSIS Catalog ;I get fail about code PAGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, codepages

I can not create SSIS catalog. When I try to this, Iget this message:

> The code page 65001 is not supported by the server. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2775)

I searched but I could not find any solutions.

Can you help me?

Comment: What steps are you doing at the time of trying to create the catalog? Help us help you; explain what you're doing and when the error happens. [SSISDB The code page 65001 is not supported by the server](https://www.google.com/search?q=SSISDB+The+code+page+65001+is+not+supported+by+the+server) gave me loads of resources; why didn't any of those help? What did you try and why did they not provide a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You don't give much information about your system etc but it is usually a system locale setting

If you are in Win10 go in control panel -> region settings -> Language for non-unicode programs -> System Locale and UNCHECK the box Beta:Use Unicode UTF-8 for worlwide Language support

Comment: Great! The same reported problem and your solution worked!